# nServicebus Operation

Tags: nservicebus

I want to use nServicebus in a new project (pub/sub) but I would like to be able to provide a UI for managing messages i.e. moving messages from 1 queue to another, monitoring message throughput, etc. I was thinking of using a database as a kind of backing store for messages and to create a UI (Web) based on that DB. I could then use the MSMQ tool that comes with nServicebus to move messages between queues. Are there other possibilities? I want to avoid using the clunky MSMQ management tools.

Answer (score 1):

We went out and purchased [Queue Explorer](http://www.cogin.com/mq/index.php).  Thus far we are happy with the product and it is a big improvement over the OOTB tooling.  We use this in combination with Performance Counters(PerfMon) to monitor queues.

Comment: +1 for queue explorer, that gives you the basic admin support you need.